# How do you configure visual studio code to run compiled Go code when using Run/Run&Debug (F5/CTRL+F5) VS code options?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have installed the following task to compile my Go project following this blog post: https://robertbasic.com/blog/build-and-run-golang-projects-in-vs-code/

**tasks.json**:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Go",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "go build",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I can compile the project using Terminal>Run build task

For running and debugging, I have created:

**launch.json**:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [],
            "env": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

But it does not work, I get the following message:

```
package .: no Go files in /usr/home/username/projects/my_app/.vscode
Process exiting with code: 1 signal: false
```

Visual Studio Code under FreeBSD12.1 (probably not relevant).

What do I have to do to get the program running when using F5/CTRL+F5?
Any tip including recommended help section or blog entry is welcomed.

Comment: go command is running under .vscode folder you just need to fix directory in which code is run

Comment: The issue was also that I was not being launching F5 from the main package.

Comment: In most projects, I change program to `${workspaceFolder}` or `${workspaceFolder}/cmd/myproject` or whatever folder contains my main package and this is the equivalent to running `go run .` in that folder. That way it doesn't matter which go file you currently have open (if it's even a go file), it'll just debug. All other values are usually left default except for the occaisonal `args` or `env` addition.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming my main package is at the root folder of the workspace, I always define the same `.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

From there, I can press <kbd>F5</kbd> from anywhere/any file, and the debug session simply starts.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Thank you so much Von! Fixed my issue.

Comment: @pandascope Well done! I am glad this answer is still helpful.